# How to split bigrams in python?

Tags: python, nlp

I have prepared bigrams for each row but now I need to split them row by row. The final result is to get rows for all bigrams with identifying columns.

This is sample dataframe. What i need is to get 4 rows with

```
16/12/2020 | 001C000001M | (one, purchase)
16/12/2020 | 001C000001M | (purchase, enquiry)
07/01/2021 | 001C00000f | (getting, payment)
07/01/2021 | 001C00000f | (missing, payment)
```

[image]

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'account', 'bigrams'])

df_test = df_test.append({'date': '16/12/2020', 'account': '001C000001M', 'bigrams': "[('one', 'purchase'), ('purchase', 'enquiry')]"}, ignore_index=True)
df_test = df_test.append({'date': '07/01/2021', 'account': '001C00000f', 'bigrams': "[('getting', 'payment'), ('missing', 'payment')]"}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: It will be better, providing the input and output, so we can understand what's your purpose

Comment: Hey, I did, my input is sample dataframe I attached, my output is a dataframe like mentioned (with 4 rows)

Comment: Does the obvious thing not work? Parse the `bigrams` field and loop over it.

Answer (score 0):

Code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

df_test = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'account', 'bigrams'])

df_test = df_test.append({'date': '16/12/2020', 'account': '001C000001M', 'bigrams': "[('one', 'purchase'), ('purchase', 'enquiry')]"}, ignore_index=True)
df_test = df_test.append({'date': '07/01/2021', 'account': '001C00000f', 'bigrams': "[('getting', 'payment'), ('missing', 'payment')]"}, ignore_index=True)

# safe-convert string to list
df_test['bigrams'] = df_test['bigrams'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x))

# expolode the list to items
df_test = df_test.explode('bigrams')
print(df_test)
```

And the output is like this:

```
             date      account              bigrams
0  16/12/2020  001C000001M      (one, purchase)
0  16/12/2020  001C000001M  (purchase, enquiry)
1  07/01/2021   001C00000f   (getting, payment)
1  07/01/2021   001C00000f   (missing, payment)
```